# Get attribute value returns a string without namespace

Tags: c++, attributes, namespaces, msxml

Here is the sample of XML code :

```
<xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
```

Here is the C++ code that has to get the `ref` attribute's value :

```
    IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap* attributes_map;
    CHK_HR(node->get_attributes(&attributes_map));
    IXMLDOMNode* temp_attr_node;
    attributes_map->getNamedItem(L"ref", &temp_attr_node);
    IXMLDOMAttribute* temp_attr = static_cast<IXMLDOMAttribute*>(temp_attr_node);
    VARIANT attr_value;
    VariantInit(&attr_value);
    temp_attr->get_value(&attr_value);
    std::string attr_value_str = VariantToString(attr_value);
    std::cout << attr_value_str;
```

This code is actually working pretty well as it is printing `UBLVersionID`. But I'd like to create an XML using this "ref" value. And I'm pretty sure I'll need to get `cbc:UBLVersionID` instead. I don't know how I can get the full value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had to replace `temp_attr->get_value(&attr_value)` by `temp_attr->get_text(&attr_value)`